# Change Sublime Text 2/3 UI style?

Tags: user-interface, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have seen in many places that some the UI design of some people's Sublime Text editor [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRfZ9.png). Mine [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d6K7.png).

How would I change my UI to look like what other people have?

Comment: Check this : http://kkga.github.io/spacegray/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).
2. Search for [themes](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/theme).
3. Install theme(s) of interest.
4. Edit preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**) and alter `"theme"` key to name of `.sublime-theme` file of interest (read theme's documentation on Package Control for information). Save file.
5. Restart Sublime (necessary) for theme to take full effect.